# How to enclose a table in a div

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` contained a `table` with two rows. Everything is fine if there is space between words, But If I put a long word (like *400 characters*) in the `<td>`, the table will go out of `div`. How can I break the word and limit it in the `<div>` ?

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/y4tgzohw/) is my demo.

**html:**

```
<div id="container">
    <table>
        <td>
            <tr>
                title
            <tr>
            <tr>
                contenttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt
            </tr>
        </td>
    </table>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
#container{
    border: 2px solid;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

table{
   table-layout: fixed;
}

td{
   word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

It should be noted, that I can not define `width` for `<td>`, because I don't want identical width for all `<td>`

[Here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/mb39fs5d/5/) is what I want. *(Suppose there is no space)*, How can I do that ?

Comment: Are you looking for `word-break: break-all;`? [See MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break)

Comment: @WanderNauta you are right ...! but one thing, should I use of both `word-wrap` and `word-break` or just `word-break` ?

Comment: `word-break` should be enough, but there's no harm in using both.

Comment: @WanderNauta aright thanks, I did it and worked correctly, But I'm worried about old browser, `word-break` is a CSS3 property. is it fine for oldest browsers ?

Comment: The MDN article I linked has a compatibility table. `word-break: break-all;` is supported in every browser except Opera Mini.

Comment: @WanderNauta very well, please add a answer to my question, I will accept it as my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86694/discussion-between-sajad-and-wander-nauta).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for the word-break CSS property, which is used to specify whether to break lines within words:

```
td {
   word-wrap: break-word;
   word-break: break-all;
}
```

[Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/m73mcm74/)

Support for `word-break` is pretty good. See the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

With `table-layout: fixed` you need to set table width also:

```css
#container {
    width: 70%;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
table {
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
td {
    word-wrap: break-word
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>title</td>
            <td class="cc">contentttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I kew it (set `width`), but there is a problem, a big space between title and content ! as I said, I don't want identical `width` for all columns.