# How word-break property just breaks from space?

Tags: html, css

I have a `<td>` with `word-break: break-all;` property. It works, but I have a small problem, If I have a **long and integrated** *(without space)* text *(more than width)*,  it is very good for me, like this:

**html:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            testtttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**css:**

```
td{
    width: 50px;
    word-break: break-all;
  }
```

**output:** (that is OK)

```
+-----------50px-----------+
|testtttttttttttttttttttttt|
|tttttttttttttttttttttttttt|
|tttt                      |
+--------------------------+
```

But when I have a **long and Not integrated** *(with space)* text, it won't work correctly. like this:

```
<td>Hello world.., this is a test text. this is a test text.</td>
```

**output:**

```
+-----------50px-----------+
|Hello world.., this is a t|
|est text. this is a test t|
|ext.                      |
+--------------------------+
```

How can I fix it? I want something like this:

```
+-----------50px-----------+
|Hello world.., this is a  |
|test text. this is a test |
|text.                     |
+--------------------------+
```

Comment: Have you tried simply letting it out?
(word-break: normal)

Comment: @Coco I tried to prevent of letting it out of range.

Comment: You don't need `break-all`. See this: http://fiddle.jshell.net/m73mcm74/1/ Please refer to this answer to your earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31936379/1355315

Comment: Documentation for word-break in MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `word-break: break-all;`. What you only need is `word-wrap: break-word` (or `overflow-wrap: break-word`)

***Example***:

```css
#container {
    width: 70%;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
table {
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
td { word-wrap: break-word }
```

```html
<div id="container">
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td class="cc">contentttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt</td>
         <td class="cc">Hello world.., this is a test text. this is a test text.</td>
      </tr>     
   </table>    
</div>
```

*Fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/m73mcm74/3/*

Also, please refer to this answer to your earlier question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31936379/1355315